# Using exec() to get class instances

Tags: python, exec

I have a class and I need to use string input to create it and I've heard about `exec()`, so I tried using that and I put the string in properly yet it gives me errors, this is the `exec` line:

```
exec(" ".join(args[2:])).toString()
```

The first 2 parts of the list are not relevant. I debugged this string just to see it is correct and even tried to hardcode it and it worked, but it didn't when I used `exec`.

What is wrong with this and how can I make this right?

Appreciating all the comment :)

Edit:

The error I get is `AttributeError` saying it is a `NoneType`, although if I just hardcode it it works perfectly fine.

Comment: `exec()` doesn't return anything (well, it returns `None`, which is Python's value for "nothing"). This being said: you definitly __DONT__ want to use `exec` nor `eval` unless 1/ [you fully understand why you shouldn't](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and 2/ you really have a valid use case (hint: I've been using Python for 20+ years now and I'm still waiting for a valid use case). If you cared to [clearly explain your real problem instead](http://xyproblem.info/), we might suggest a better solution.

Comment: So I have string inputs coming from an application, and I want to convert them into code, so one option is making a lexer and parser and all of that, which I have but not too well. I think that for such a small case it really is a big of a deal to starting lexing, paring, and executing text. And then I saw this "exec" option which just allows you to take a string and conver it into code, it sounded perfect so I tried it and this is the problem I encountered. Do you have a better solution to that?

Comment: `exec()` doesn't return anything, so that's why you're getting the `AttributeError`. The function is primarily used for the side-effects of the code being executed — such as defining an instance of class. You're just not using it properly, but it's impossible to determine how to do it right without knowing the contents of `args[2:]`.

Comment: the contents of args[2:] in this case is to create a class I called Mark, it receives a date, time and a list(Date and Time are also simple classes that just contains integers and a toString() function). I tried to make an easy calender. The reason I use args[2:] and not args is because args is !DB Calender <details here> and I only want whats coming after the world Calender, I debugged it and it works properly, what's coming inside args[2:] is Mark(Date(1,1,20), Time(3, 50), ["Attempt", "One"])
(The numbers inside are just examples of dates and times but you get the point)

Comment: You should read the first link in my previous comment... passing user inputs to `exec()` or `eval` is the epitome of "insecure".

Comment: I read it, and I understand, that's why I asked if there is an alternative that's not too big like creating a lexer and etc

Comment: Defining a class is not the same thing as creating an instance of one, so unless `.toString()` is a _class_ method, as opposed to a normal instance method, your code wouldn't work (even if the `exec()` function returned something). In addition I second @bruno's suggestion to read up on how using `exec()` is often a security issue — in other words, you probably should even be trying to use it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: instead of passing a Python expression, either use argparse's subcommands or define your own easily-parsable mini-language. You can store relevant classes and functions in a dict to get them from strings (better than relying on `globals` as it lets you whitelist only what you want to expose)

Solution 2: use the full power of the `ast` module to parse the Python expression into an ast then write your own visitors to safely evaluate the ast.

Solution 3: keep on using `exec` or `eval` and wait until some script kiddie erases your full hard-drive or worse.